# How to access FTP with read AND write access in finder?

Tags: macos, finder, ftp

I just read that finder has purposely restricted access when it comes to connecting to FTP sites. Not sure how any apple exec could possibly think this is acceptable. Simply put, I need to find a way to force finder to allow write access for a FTP server. Transmit no longer provides this functionality. Im not looking for any third party software. There should be a terminal command that forces finder to allow access?

Comment: It is acceptable because FTP is a horribly insecure protocol.  Transmit 5 supports FTP and there are several methods to install FTP clients via the command line (https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/07/get-install-ftp-mac-os/).

Comment: Macos has behaved this way for at least 13 years and maybe 20.